# What is a good solvent for pentacene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, solvents, hydrocarbons

I am doing an experiment with pentacene molecule ($\ce{C22H14}$). I want to clean my sample reservoir after using it.
But I show in some literature that it is slightly soluble in organic solvent. Could you please suggest me a solvent for pentacene ?

Comment: Something high boiling.  Try toluene, chlorobenzene etc and scratching.  Otherwise chromic mixture if allowed, or "piranha". Skill needed for the last two.

Comment: @Alchimista Why not write an answer? ;)

Comment: It does not qualify as an answer in my opinion. Pentacene is a hard beast. The OP should try aromatic high boiling and rubbing. If he/she would have ask how to prepare a solution sensibly containing Pentacene , I would have commented "forget". @Gaurang Tandon

Comment: If you can heat your container strongly, it should burn off easily in air above ~500 °C, or even down to about ~350 °C, though in the latter case it may take a whole day.